# Meeting place in CDG

Tags: cdg

I will be arriving into terminal 1 at CDG and other family members will be arriving into terminal 2B.  Where is the best place to meet to after collecting our bags and to meet our shuttle to the city?

Comment: I would meet closest to the terminal where the group arriving last lands, so those arriving first have the time to get to the other terminal. Other than that, I can't see any reason to prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 3):

Roissy-Charles de Gaulle (CDG) is not the easiest in which to do this but there are many official, signed meeting points in each terminal. They're landside, after baggage claim and close to the Aéroports de Paris information counters.
You might arrange to meet at the shuttle; you don't say which one you're taking, or who is arriving first/earlier.  Terminal 2 is very large, and you get to it from Terminals 1 and 3 by taking the [CDGVAL airport shuttle trains](http://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/transfer-terminal-1/).

Referencing the [airport map](http://easycdg.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Plan-A%C3%A9roport-Paris-Roissy-Charles-de-Gaulle.png), you can select a meeting point that works best for you and your family, depending on arrival times and gates, and your shuttle connection. They are located in:

- Terminal 1 Arrivals level, close to Exit 34
- Terminal 2A Opposite Exit 4-5
- Terminal 2C Opposite Exit 5-6
- Terminal 2D Opposite Exit 6, opposite Exit 7 (two baggage claim facilities)
- Terminal 2E Arrivals level, opposite Exit 8-10
- Terminal 2F Arrivals level, opposite Exit 8-10
- Terminal 2G Main hall
- Terminal 3 Arrivals hall